# Difference "There is be" - "There be"

Tags: difference

What is the difference between

> There got to be something wrong with him.

> There's got to be something wrong with him.

I don't understand the function of 's.

Comment: _There's_ is _there has_ in this case. Knowing that, I think the duplicates should be helpful. If you are still confused, please [edit] your post to explain why, and your question will be reopened.

Comment: _There got to be_ is not correct English, though it might be used in very informal speech.